# Postfix + sasl method rimap strips domain name from user

Tags: postfix, sasl, saslauthd

I'm setting up a mail server with Postfix and Courier-IMAP. I'd like to do SMTP authentication with rimap, so that I don't have to maintain two user DB's. The problem I'm having, is that the username postfix passes is stripped of its domain name. It should be 'john@domain.com' and it becomes 'john'.

Logging into the IMAP server works, so does `testsaslauthd -u john@domain.com -p password`.

Using `smtpd_sasl_local_domain` (setting or unsetting it) doesn't make a difference.

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/140731/postfix-removing-domain-from-user-names-before-passing-to-dovecot-for-imap-authe) doesn't seem to be it. Even when I try to login with uasdfer@asdfasdf it strips the domain part off.

Postfix sasl:

```
# cat main.cf |grep -i sasl
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf
```

Sasl config:

```
# cat saslauthd |grep -v "#"|grep -v -E "^$"
START=yes
DESC="SASL Authentication Daemon"
NAME="saslauthd"
MECHANISMS="rimap"
MECH_OPTIONS="127.0.0.1"
THREADS=5
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/run/saslauthd"
```

Server versions:

- Debian 6.0.7
- Postfix 2.7.1-1+squeeze1
- Courier 4.8.0-3

Comment: if you add `-r` to your saslauthd OPTIONS?

Comment: My problem was this *and* that Postfix is chroot-jailed so `/var/run/saslauthd` becomes `/var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably just need to add `-r` to your saslauthd `OPTIONS=` stanza.

From [the man pages](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/saslauthd8.html)

```
 -r          Combine the realm with the login (with an ’@’ sign in between).  
             e.g.  login: "foo" realm: "bar" will get passed as login:
             "foo@bar".  Note that the realm will still be passed, which may
             lead to unexpected behavior.
```

Comment: No problems, happy to have helped!